# Integrating NavigatorIOS with UINavigationController stack (obj C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

Now I've read the instruction on how to [integrate React Native into your Objective C app.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content)

Is it possible to link the stack of your UINavigationController (Objective C navigator) with the [NavigatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#content) in React Native?